# Geometrically Constructible Angles and unit intervals

Tags: geometry

Constructible angles = 3n degrees
How do we construct angle 36 degrees and 3 degrees using geometric theorems?

Comment: Welcome to mathematics SE. What have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

For 36 degrees -- and I don't claim that this is the most efficient way to do this, but it will work -- use one of the many methods for inscribing a pentagon in a circle.  You only need two points of the pentagon.  The angle the center of the pentagon makes with any two nearest-neighbor vertices is 72 degrees.  So once you have your pentagon vertices, bisect that angle to get 36 degrees.

UPDATE:  For three degrees, again, I don't claim that this is a particularly efficient way to do it, but it will work:  You can get a 72 degree angle from the pentagon as above.  You can also easily construct a 60 degree angle.  So, 72-60=12.  Bisect that angle and you get 6 degrees.  Bisect *that* angle again and you get 3.